# Laravel - Repopulate checkbox to ticked or unticked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

In Laravel, if validation failed, it goes back to a same form page. How to repopulate a checkbox to ticked or unticked?

By default, it should be unticked when loading on the page for the first time.

```
{{ Form::checkbox('custom_address', false, 
   Input::old('custom_address'), array('class' => 'test')); }}
```

Comment: `return Redirect::to('form')->withInput();` See http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#old-input

Comment: @NilotpalBarpujari Yes I already got that, `return Redirect::to('/order/details')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a value for your checkbox, otherwise the `Input` class will always have it empty / unchecked.

Give the checkbox a value of 1, then it should work.

```
{{ Form::checkbox('custom_address', 1, Input::old('custom_address'), array('class' => 'test')); }}
```

Answer (score -1):

just use a conditional.

```
@if(!empty(Input::old('custom_adress')))

{{ Form::checkbox('custom_address', true, 
Input::old('custom_address'), array('class' => 'test')); }}

@else

{{ Form::checkbox('custom_address', false, 
Input::old('custom_address'), array('class' => 'test')); }}

@endif
```

Comment: You should never duplicate your code like this. It can lead to a maintenance nightmare. For example, what happens if down the road someone makes a change to the code but doesn't do the change in both places?

Comment: that's call _error in judgement_ in my opinion. when you see a conditional, and if you make a change, you must check all other conditions too.