# Laravel PHP: Do not display 'blank' checkbox data in view

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel-4

I have a form that contains checkboxes.  After the form is submitted, the user is taken back to the view 'index.blade.php'.  In 'index.blade.php', I do not want 'blank' checkbox data to be displayed, only checkbox data that the user selected.  I am displaying the checkbox data as 'li' elements.

**View(index.blade.php):**

```
@foreach($allStones as $stone)
                    <tr>
                         <td>{{ $stone->stone_id }}</b></td>
                         <td>{{ $stone->stone_name }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $stone->stone_type }}</td>
                         <td>
                            /* Checkbox data */ 
                            /* Only display checkbox data that is checked */
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_black}}</li>
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_blue }}</li> 
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_brown }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_gold }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_gray }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_green }}</li> 
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_red }}</li> 
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_color_white }}</li>
                        </td>
                         <td>{{ $stone->stone_origin }}</td>
                         <td>{{ $stone->stone_pattern }}</td>
                         <td>
                            /* Checkbox data */ 
                            /* Only display checkbox data that is checked. */
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_application_kitchen}}</li>
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_application_bathroom }}</li> 
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_application_fireplace }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_application_floor }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $stone->stone_application_outdoor }}</li>
                        </td>
                         <td><b>{{ link_to_route('show_stone', 'Edit', array($stone->stone_id)) }}</b></td>
                    </tr>     
                    @endforeach
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $allStones = Stone::paginate(10);
    $this->layout->content = \View::make('home.index', array('allStones' => $allStones));
}
```

Is there a simple way of accomplishing this task instead of having 'blank' checkbox data displayed?

Comment: check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869262/laravel-repopulate-checkbox-to-ticked-or-unticked/26869534#26869534) similiar question.

Comment: This solution has the checkboxes with a default setting of 'checked'.  In the form, the checkboxes should by default be unchecked.  It accepts unchecked checkboxes fine as 'blank', I just don't want the 'blank' data to be displayed as an 'li' element.

Comment: I actually found a way to 'cheat' this problem by adding 'text-decoration:none' to your CSS file.  The 'li' elements with the blank data will still be present but there won't be any extra space when displaying your data.  Probably not the best solution in the world but gets the job done lol.

Comment: just use a conditional.

Comment: That's probably the cleanest approach to this problem but I found by using CSS, 'text-decoration:none' only displays checkbox data that is actually selected/checked.